# Logging faces with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, database, computer-vision

I'm pretty new to OpenCV. Basically I want my RPi to do facial recognition with OpenCV and then log (save only the face as a picture) and store it in a database. How would I achieve this? I also want it to log the time/date and potentially the GPS coordinates of the capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and then log (save only the face as a picture)

I take it that you need just the face, and not a name to go with the face. If so, you should implement just *face detection*, not *face recognition*. 
Have a look at the facedetect project in opencv samples distribution. A more thorough source of information is the [Mastering OpenCV book (Chapter 8).](http://www.packtpub.com/cool-projects-with-opencv/book)

You also need to think about environmental conditions, such as ambient lighting. Face detection doesn't work well in low light / night conditions. You may have to setup an IR illuminator and remove the IR filter of your camera to capture faces at night.

> log the time/date

The pi does not have a realtime clock to track time.
Either have your Pi connected to Internet all the time so that it can get current date/time over NTP.
Or buy a RTC module and connect it via GPIO pins.

> GPS coordinates

If the camera you are using is location capable, you can extract GPS position from the EXIF metadata in image.
Otherwise, you'll need a GPS module connected via GPIO pins. Or a secondary device like a GPS capable mobile phone to provide the coordinates to the Pi over a network connection.